# Data loaded twice into application

Tags: vb.net, compilation, dataset

I've got a problem in a VB.Net application. This issue appears when application loads data from database into a `dataset`. Then I store this data into objects. The bug is that sometimes it loads data twice, sometimes only once. I tried to debug it, but it works perfectly in debug. There is always one data loading.

It looks like if the application tried to do two things at the same time. This bug does not happen every time. It appears mostly on a certain type of computer. Could that be a x86 / x64 problem or a compile option? I currently compile in AnyCPU platform, but I tried both x64 and x86 and it does not improve it.

This is the load function :

```
  'Load the tree view of a locnum
Private Sub LoadData()

    'prepare data to be imported to the application
    ta.BB_RULES_PrepareDataSp(GridLocnum.SelectedCells(0).Value)
    'load data
    Me.W_RULESTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BOMBuilderDataSet.W_RULES)
    Me.W_RULESTableAdapter.GetData()
    StoreData.GetData.Process(Me.BOMBuilderDataSet.Tables("W_RULES"))
    'delete data from working table
    ta.BB_RULES_DeleteDataSp()
    'show data
    Tree_ShowData()
End Sub
```

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Please show us what you have done. Without providing any code we can't help as to what may be wrong as we can't see it.

Comment: It's difficult to help without code available to examine. Based on what little information is in the question, the architecture is less likely to be the problem than you think...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite hard to give you my code because it's my society code. Also, Data loading into Dataset is handled by .Net framework. The only thing I do is that I read each table line to insert it into objects. I can tell you that each data appears only once. When I debug my code, everything goes fine. It is only when I compile it and make a .exe file that it bugs (on some computers but not all, and not every time...)

Comment: Insert Me.BOMBuilderDataSet.W_RULES.Clear() before Me.W_RULESTableAdapter.Fill() and see i you can reproduce the problem again.

Comment: It's not working better with the Clear. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my VS2013, and I disabled an option in the `Advanced Compiler Settings` (`Compile` tab in project properties) and it seems to solve my issue...